# how to prevent the $result in mysql query from looping the wrong way

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in my following code. I want all data associated with the selected id of the dropdownlist to be viewed in the textboxes as well as inside the table.

When I ran my code, the result of the query created a repetitive result because of the data inside the database is more than 1 row.

What am I missing here? Did Inmake mistakes in the normalization of the database? Can somebody help me?

below is my code in search.php

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("dbconnect.php");

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM kursus";
$result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query1);
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM kursus");

?>

<html>
<head>

<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
   return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
       document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
  }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","search2.php?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
    Carian :  <select id="id_kursus" name="id_kursus" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <option>Sila Pilih</option>
                  <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
                    echo "<option value='".$row1['id_kursus']."'>".$row1['nama_kursus']."</option>";
                  }                      
                  ?>
              </select>



  </form>
    <br>
  <div id="txtHint"><b>Result will be display here.</div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

below is my codes in search2.php

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <?php

 $q = intval($_GET['q']);

 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin','tracer');
 if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }

 mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");

 $sql = "SELECT 
            a.*,
            b.*,
            c.*,         
            a.id_kursus AS id_kursus

          FROM pelatih a
          LEFT JOIN kursus b ON b.id_kursus = a.id_kursus
          RIGHT JOIN  status_pelatih c ON c.id_status_semasa = a.id_status_semasa

          WHERE a.id_kursus = '.$q.'";



 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $no = 1;

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  

  echo "<table class='table1'>
    <tr>
      <td>Kod Kursus : </td>
      <td><input type='text' value= '$row[kod_kursus]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nama Kursus : </td>
      <td><input type='text' size='40' value= '$row[nama_kursus]'></td>          
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sesi : </td>
      <td><input type='text' value= '$row[sesi_kursus]''></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Batch : </td>
      <td><input type='text' value= '$row[batch_kursus]'></td>
    </tr>                  
    <tr>
      <td>Tempoh Kursus :</td>
      <td><input type='date' value= '$row[tarikh_mula_kursus]'> Hingga <input type='date' value= '$row[tarikh_tamat_kursus]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Program Tajaan : </td>
      <td><input type='text' value= '$row[penaja_program]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Peruntukan : </td>
      <td><input type='text' value= '$row[peruntukan]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tarikh Kajiselidik : </td>
      <td ><input type='date' value= '$row[tarikh_kajiselidik]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara Kajiselidik : </td>
      <td ><input type='text' value= '$row[cara_kajiselidik]'></td>
    </tr>
 </table>

  <br>";

  echo "<table class='table2'>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan='2'>Bil</th>
    <th colspan='4'>Nama dan Butiran Pelatih</th>
    <th colspan='6'>Maklumat Tracer Study</th>       
  </tr>
  <tr>        
    <th>Nama Pelatih</th>
    <th>No. K/P</th>
    <th>No. Telefon</th>
    <th>Status Semasa</th>
    <th>Nama Syarikat</th>
    <th>Alamat Syarikat</th>
    <th>No. Telefon</th>
    <th>Nama Jawatan</th>
    <th>Tangga Gaji</th>
    <th>Catatan</th>
 </tr>";

                 echo '<tr>
                          <td>'.$no.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row['nama_pelatih'].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row['ic_pelatih'].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row['tel_pelatih'].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row['status_semasa_pelatih'].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row['nama_syarikat'].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row['alamat_syarikat'].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row['tel_syarikat']. '</td>
                          <td>'.$row['jawatan'].'</td>
                          <td> RM'.$row['tangga_gaji'].'</td>
                          <td>'.$row['catatan'].'</td>
                      </tr>';
                $no++;
      }
      echo "</table>";

      mysqli_close($con);

      ?>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Without seeing your expected output, table structure and data it's hard to see what is wrong with this.

Comment: Read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), your application is vulnerable.

Comment: Not sure about the `RIGHT JOIN` in the query, do you really want your main table to be optional?

Comment: Nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN precisely because of it's counterintuitiveness and propensity for misuse - you've written an inner join instead of an outer one. This isn't the cause of your problem however

Comment: @Nick my expected output is i want the table to display once and the data inside the second image above is just like the first image. for example: when user select the dropdownlist, the data below for the table will be 

1.Alif 
2.Aizat

only in 1 table

Comment: Gotcha. Simplest way to achieve that is to wrap the code for `<table class="table1">` inside an `if ($no == 1) {}`

Comment: @Nick can u show me how to do it?

Comment: I think putting `if ($no == 1) {` before this line: `echo "<table class='table1'>` and `}` after these lines: `<th>Catatan</th> </tr>";` should work.

Comment: @Nick it works perfectly..thanks